# Firebase cloud function first invocation after deploy times-out

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a HTTP cloud function for firebase. However after deploy, the very first invocation returns a timeout error code. I'm using volley library for Android to invoke the HTTP function.
Subsequent invocations seem to work perfectly.

What I've done: I felt the issue maybe a cold start time problem however I tried increasing the timeout duration from code to 180secs. Yet I still get the same issue

Code: Shows the complete cloud function with the issue

```
const runtimeOptsActivateApp = {
  timeoutSeconds: 180,
  memory: '128MB'
}

exports.activateApp = functions.runWith(runtimeOptsActivateApp).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const pin = req.query.pin;
  const id_token = req.query.auth;
  let docId;
  let uid;
  let email;

  // idToken comes from the client app
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(id_token)
  .then(decodedToken => {
    uid = decodedToken.uid;
    email = decodedToken.email;

    return activationPinsRef
      .where("pin", "==", pin)
      .get()

  })
  .then(querySnapshot=>{
    if(querySnapshot.empty){
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Activation pin does not exist..."))
    }

    return activationPinsRef
      .where("pin", "==", pin)
      .where("is_blocked", "==", false)
      .get()

  })
  .then(querySnapshot=>{
    if(querySnapshot.empty){
      return Promise.reject(new Error("User has been blocked..."))
    }

    return activationPinsRef
      .where("pin", "==", pin)
      .where("is_blocked", "==", false)
      .where("has_activated", "==", false)
      .get()

  })
  .then(querySnapshot=>{
    if(querySnapshot.empty){
      console.log("User has activated, He may be trying to reactivate, verify his activation status in users document!")
      return usersRef
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
    }

    console.log("User is a trying to activate for the first time!")
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
      docId = documentSnapshot.id;
    })
    return activationPinsRef
      .doc(docId)
      .update({
        "has_activated": true,
        "uid_activated": uid,
        "time_activated": Date.now()
      })

  })
  .then(result => {

    if(result instanceof admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot){
      var is_activated = result.data().is_activated;
      if(is_activated){
        console.log('Reactivation successful!!!');
        return res.status(200).send({
          "status": "success",
          "is_reactivation": true
        })
      }
      return Promise.reject(new Error("User is_activated field is false!"))
    }

    usersRef
      .doc(uid)
      .update({
        is_activated:true
      })

    return res.status(200).send({
      "status": "success",
      "is_reactivation": false
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(401).end()
  })

});
```

Comment: Hello, you should add to your question the entire code of your Cloud Function. Without seeing the code it is nearly impossible to help you. Thx.

Comment: Hello Renaud, I've just updated the question with relevant code.